# Using Facebook Graph API from a mobile application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I have a small [card game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) at Facebook (and few Russian social networks), which gets user's id, first name and avatar through the old REST API.

Now I'm trying to develop the same game as a mobile app with **Flex** Hero SDK for Android and iPhone. Which means I can't use native SDKs for those platforms, but have to use [OAuth as descibed at Facebook page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile).

[image]

I'm trying to write a short PHP script, which would return the user information as XML to my mobile app. My script can get the token already:

```
<?php
define('FB_API_ID', 'XXX');
define('FB_AUTH_SECRET', 'XXX');
$code = @$_GET['code'];

# this is just a link for me, for development puposes
if (!isset($code)) {
        $str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' . FB_API_ID .
                '&redirect_uri=http://preferans.de/facebook/mobile.php&display=touch';
        print "<html><body><a href=\"$str\">$str</a></body></html>";
        exit();
}

$req = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . FB_API_ID .
'&redirect_uri=http://preferans.de/facebook/mobile.php&client_secret=' . FB_AUTH_SECRET .
'&code=' . $code;

$ch = curl_init($req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch))
        exit('Download failed');
curl_close($ch);

parse_str($page, $data);

#header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
#print('<?xml version="1.0"? ><app>');
print_r($data);
#print('</app>');
?>
```

This works well and I get back the token:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => 262578703638|2.OwBuoa2fT5Zp_yo2hFUadA__.3600.1294904800-587287941|ycUNaHVxa_8mvenB9JB1FH3DcAA
    [expires] => 6697
)
```

But how can I use this token now to find the user's name and avatar and especially I'm confused by how will I get the current user id?

While using REST API I've always known the current user id by calling `$userid=$fb->require_login()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Use curl to request: https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=XXXXXXX

The "/me" will get you all of the info you need.

```
$req = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=' . $access_token;
$ch = curl_init($req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch))
        exit('Download failed');
curl_close($ch);

$user_object = json_decode($page);

var_dump($user_object);
```

Will return something like:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (20) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(10) "1017193642"
  ["name"]=>
  string(19) "Lance Scott Rushing"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(5) "Lance"
  ["middle_name"]=>
  string(5) "Scott"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(7) "Rushing"
  ["link"]=>
  string(36) "http://www.facebook.com/LanceRushing"
  .....
```

Comment: Thank you this works well. I just wonder, why is my avatar is not among the returned data and if I can reduce the returned data to the things I need (currently it returns too many data, including my bio, location, etc.)

Comment: you can request https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=XXXXX  This will 302 redirect to the user's picture.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add comments I'll answer here.

In order to get the profile picture you need to request `https://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture`. If you want only specific fields you can specify it this way: `https://graph.facebook.com/ID?fields=uid,name,etc&access_token=token`

Alternatively you can use the PHP SDK to authorise and log in the user so that you don't have to get the token manually - it would simplify your code. For instance, instead of every cURL request you could just do `$facebook->api(request);` A good description and example are here http://apps.facebook.com/graphapidemo/.

Comment: Thank you for this info! Unfortunately after some thought I can't see how to use this API for my mobile Flex application, because I need to pass a string to my mobile app. But all this stuff happens in a browser at the mobile phone. I.e. I don't see the way to pass data from browser to the app :-(

Comment: Oh actually I can use StageWebView and listen for its location changes: http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/tag/stagewebview